# Achartengine Annotation Alignment

Tags: annotations, alignment, achartengine

I am trying to align the annotation provided by the achartengine according to a given condition but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the annotation's alignment. The alignment that takes affect is always the one that is provided in the first IF condition. Could anyone please point out the problem? Below is my code

```
int xaxis = 1;

for(int yaxis = 0; yaxis < scaleData.length; yaxis++)
{
    factorsSeries.addAnnotation(annotationDate, xaxis,
                scaleData[yaxis]+0.2);

    if(xaxis == 1)
    {
        r.setAnnotationsTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);

        Toast.makeText(Graphs_MulipleDatesAllinOne.this, 
                "setAnnotationsTextAlign(Align.RIGHT)", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(xaxis == 6)
    {
        r.setAnnotationsTextAlign(Align.LEFT);

        Toast.makeText(Graphs_MulipleDatesAllinOne.this, 
                "setAnnotationsTextAlign(Align.LEFT)", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        r.setAnnotationsTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

        Toast.makeText(Graphs_MulipleDatesAllinOne.this, 
                "setAnnotationsTextAlign(Align.CENTER)", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    xaxis++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `xaxis` in your code is always `1`. Note that you are iterating on `yaxis` and the if conditions are on `xaxis`.

Comment: But I am incrementing xaxis++ at the end of FOR loop. Should it not work?